# Alert, confirm, and prompt not working after using History API on Safari, iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, back-button, browser-history

After calling `history.pushState` in Safari on iOS, it's no longer possible to use `alert()`, `confirm()` or `prompt()`, when using the browser back button to change back.

Is this an iOS bug? Are there any known workarounds?

Simple example to reproduce this behavior:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>Step 1: <button onclick="alert(Math.random())">Confirm Alert is working</button></li>
      <li>Step 2: <button onclick="history.pushState(null, null, '/debug/'+Math.random());">Change History</button></li>
      <li>Step 3: use your browser back button, to go back</li>
      <li>Step 4: <button onclick="alert(Math.random())">Alert is not working anymore</button></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can try it online here: [goo.gl/faFW6o](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/6eab8028289c64a623efcba652eb7446/raw/be9ecb6c2d08497a146b947266c06a0409aaeb5b/test.html).

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7MTgwGZWT0mXCSDBEp2b?p=preview

Comment: @JacobHeater unfortunately its not when running standalone (without an iframe)

Comment: @JacobHeater I've added a live demo to the description. Please feel free to try it out over there.

Comment: It's working for me using the link your provided.

Comment: Are you testing on Safari iOS?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't read that little caveat.

Comment: Same issue! I don't know what to do.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on iOS. I can find very little via web searching. Here's someone else with the same problem: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65054#198030

Comment: Seeing the same thing even on iOS 12.0.1. Seems like a bug indeed. Have you filed a radar with apple (bugreport.apple.com) about this?

Comment: I opened rdar://45141145 with the reproduction steps above. They asked me to submit a sysdiagnose and a video of the issue as well, which I have just done.

Comment: "Engineering has determined that your bug report (45141145) is a duplicate of 25868851 and will be closed."

Comment: @tmm1 as rdar is only for Apple engineers, I can't see 25868851. Could you please share the progress of that radar?

Comment: I cannot see that radar either, because I didn't create it. All I can see is my radar, which was closed because it is duplicate.

Comment: Here are my findings, once you use ios safari back button, I think browser loading content from cache, therefore js is not working. Instead of using back button using window.history.go(-1) works.
I tried to detect back buttons but I've failed.
Additionally tried this but it didn't refresh. Maybe I'm missing something
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
};

Comment: works for me so it does

Comment: Still a bug in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the back-forward cache in Safari.

You can use the following code to force a reload when the back-button is pressed.

```
window.onpageshow = function(e) { // e -> event
    if (e.persisted) {
        window.location.reload(); 
    }
};
```

Additionally, if you are using jQuery ...

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function(e) { // e -> event
    if (e.originalEvent.persisted) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

one workaround would be instead the property onload on the button, create a function adding the listeners then call it on window.onpopstate and window.onload..