# iPhone Safari browser, change # hash URL and then Javascript alert message box stop working

Tags: javascript, iphone, browser, safari, alert

I run a web page in iPhone Safari. The page has a button. on clicking it, will show an alert message box. This is OK. Then, I change or add # hash URL **by typing in the address bar**, then, alert message box stop working. I click the button, and nothing happens. No javascript error but no alert message box.

[image: video recording of the issue]

Is this iOS Safari known issue?

Please share your thoughts and the solution you have come up with. Many Thanks!

```js
$(".button").click(function () {
  alert('Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="button" type="button" value="alert" />
```

**Note**:

- This is not quite due to my code. I have also tested at
  [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)
- I have tested in the most recent iOS versions.
- Javascript itself is working
- Not JQuery issue, plain JS code also does not work
- An alert box is working in iPhone Chrome or other browsers

Comment: Can you add your button html and the js code to trigger the alert?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani this is not my code's issue. I have tested at w3school alert message tutorial, and there also happens this issue.

Comment: This code snippet works fine, even in iOS Safari, even when adding a fragment to the URL.

Comment: @deceze please try 2 times in consecutive without reloading. first try is OK. second try (change # part), and will not be OK.

Comment: Did you test anywhere else?

Comment: @zearthur99 also tested in iPad, and see the same issue there.

Comment: I can replicate this issue on an iPad, as described here.  A solitary `#` works, `#hash` works but having the slash `#/hash` does not.

Comment: ...actually, sometimes it works.

Comment: Have you tried using .on('click') instead of .click?

Comment: @Saeed.Gh yes, but also does not work

Comment: `#` is a fragment separator. In safari Mobile, if you append anything with `#` url and click **go** page is not actually reloading; instead safari is trying to locate the fragment in the webpage and I believe it is what is causing the alert not to function. But if you reload the page manually even with `#`, alert works fine.

Comment: @SarathDamaraju As I know, JS client apps usually changes # part without reloading the page. so Safari Mobile is not going to work with this approach ? and is that normal or a bug ?

Comment: @PyaePhyoAung , Not reloading a page is normal but preventing functionalities like alerts should be considered as a bug unless specified somewhere by safari dev team.

Comment: Looks like the issue with `alert` method itself. I see it as a call on onclick when recording the timeline, but it does not show anything. As a possible temp solution - reload page on url hash changed - alerts will work until next hash change.

Comment: Aside from this bug, using the **alert** function is kind of frowned upon these days. It is now customary to use **console.log** for debugging stuff, or creating a custom **z-index**ed popup for displaying information to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Could be related to [Alert, confirm, and prompt not working after using History API on Safari, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083702/alert-confirm-and-prompt-not-working-after-using-history-api-on-safari-ios) and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65054

It seems that `alert()` becomes `undefined`. A suggested workaround is to use custom popups instead.

Answer (score 0):

Never used a `#` inside a url other than as a reference to an anchor, but i'm not 100% sure about this...
I think that adding a `#` to the url and pressing enter won't reload the page. The `#abc` in the url does tell the browser to jump to an anchor named `abc` and so this will never reload the page or trigger some javascript. If you don't want to jump/scroll to some anchor insite your actual page, don't use `#` within the url. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The # in a url is a fragment identifier. It is expecting something to be after the url example: www.yourpage.com/foo.html#bar. This leaves it looking for the bar fragment in your page. The page will not be reloaded.

[This might help w3 fragments](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be due to the fact that you're not making another `http request` and instead instructing the browser to go to that said hash of (an example) #abc.

If you had an element of some sorts like this with that id, it would jump to that section of the page.

Example:

```html
<a href="#abc">click to jump down to my section</a>

<p id="abc">my section</p>
```

I'm assuming when you type #abc in the url, it will be looking for that. Which isn't there, of course.

Other than that, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I believe changing or pressing enter in the address bar always makes a new request in any browser. This rule only applies anchors