# IOS Safari window.alert, window.confirm not working after onpopstate triggered

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

After onpopstate event triggered, window.alert, window.confirm etc not working.

[This is related console logs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aODGM.png)

And this is what I tested.

- First I registered `popstate` event.
- And tried `window.alert('abc');` // It works.
- Tried `history.back()` or click back button, then `popstate` event triggered.
- And tried `window.alert('abc');` // Not working.

> I found the same issue, there is no answers left, so I post a question once again.
>   [Alert, confirm, and prompt not working after using History API on Safari, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083702/alert-confirm-and-prompt-not-working-after-using-history-api-on-safari-ios)

- I can't do `location.reload` inside the `onpopstate` event because of some issues.

Is there any ios bug report?
or.. Does anyone know why this happenes or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve this issue.
I had to change window.alert to some custom layer.