# window.confirm not working on iphone not working

Tags: reactjs

I have a web page with following event:

```
const onDeleteBankData = async (bankData) => {
   if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this item?')) {
     return;
   } 
}
```

I tested it in Chrome and on an Android device and it works. However on iPhone this does not work. Is this expected behavior? Is it a browser thing, or something I need to setup in REACT?

Comment: do you tested on Chrome on iphone  or only with safari ?

Comment: Safari only. Do you know if it should work? Maybe iPhone safari does not accept confims?

Comment: do you have error in console ?  try replace with alert ? 
It should but i did'nt tested it.


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022927/ios-safari-window-alert-window-confirm-not-working-after-onpopstate-triggered


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083702/alert-confirm-and-prompt-not-working-after-using-history-api-on-safari-ios

Comment: I dont know how to get console on iphone. But I tried replacing it with a bootstrap modal and that works.